# Publish MassTransit messages from Consumer with IPublishEndpoint and EF Outbox

Tags: c#, masstransit

I have an Azure Function in C# that listens to a Service Bus queue and consumes the message with a MassTransit `IConsumer`. That message had been published from a different Web Application to a Service Bus Topic and then redirected to that queue through a subscription to the topic.
Now, I have configured MassTransit to use the Entity Framework Outbox, which works perfectly fine if I try to publish a message from the Azure Function outside of an `IConsumer`. However, it doesn't work within the `IConsumer`.
My understanding is that this is not possible, because I should use the `ConsumeContext` that I get back from the Consumer:

> Once you have consumers you will ALWAYS use ConsumeContext to interact with the bus, and never the IBus.

The problem with this approach is that I cannot leverage DI and cannot separate my concerns. In other terms, I want to be able to collect all events that are eligible to become MassTransit messages within a transaction scope and raise all of them through my `IIntegrationEventPublisher`

```cs
internal abstract class IntegrationEventPublisher<TDbContext> : IIntegrationEventPublisher
    where TDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IPublishEndpoint _publishEndpoint;
    private readonly TDbContext _dbContext;

    public IntegrationEventPublisher(
        IPublishEndpoint publishEndpoint,
        TDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _publishEndpoint = publishEndpoint;
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    protected virtual Uri DestinationAddress { get; set; } = default!;

    private async Task PublishEventsAsync<T>(
        T integrationEvent,
        bool saveChanges,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        where T : IntegrationEvent
    {
        await _publishEndpoint.Publish(
            integrationEvent,
            integrationEvent.GetType(), 
            c =>
            {
                c.DestinationAddress = DestinationAddress;
                c.Headers.Set(CustomHeaders.EventType, integrationEvent.GetType().FullName);
            },
            cancellationToken);

        if (saveChanges)
        {
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Please notice, in the code above, I'm adding a bool to choose whether to call `SaveChangesAsync` for the EF Outbox to kick in, but in my scenario most of the time I don't require it (if I have already a transaction opened, I'll rely on that doing the SaveChanges at some point).

Is there a way to achieve this by injecting something different? I also noticed, in this scenario, that the `IPublishEndpoint` is of type `ConsumeContextScope<TheEventImConsuming>`, whereas I would need a brand-new publish endpoint.

I didn't really figure out a way to make this work, either with or without the outbox. Without the outbox and passing the `ConsumeContext` to the function, I managed to publish the message, but it didn't really respected the `integrationEvent.GetType()` nor the `DestinationAddress`. And I would like to avoid that, if possible...